# Run ASP.NET MVC Application on Hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it necessary that we need to install asp.net mvc on hosting server to run application develop in asp.net mvc?

I had developed a application and i am uploading on ixwebhosting hosting.

my application is not working.

Comment: "my application is not working." - how about saying what is not working and the error that you are getting. "is not working" doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the host supports ASP.NET 2.0 or later I think you should be able to just include the System.Web.MVC DLLs in your bin folder when you deploy to the server. The DLLs you need are:

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

See Phil Haack's article on [bin-deploying with MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).